# How can I view ALL files in the current directory when I "Open...", "Save...", "Save As..."

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, dialog, file-filter

I'd like the "Open..." , "Save..." and "Save As..." standard Windows dialog boxes to, **by default**, show all files in the dialog box, not just the ones that correspond with the current "Save as" type.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type `*.*` into the "File name" field then <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the wildcard pattern will be applied regardless of the filter chosen

Another way is to type the name with quotes `"like this.whatever"` before saving

Comment: Thank you for the input and I know this would work. But I really want to be able to set "show all files" as the default option whenever I open the dialog box. It would save me quite a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can't. The filters that appear are determined by the programmer of the application when the [Open/SaveAs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes) dialog is called and they also dictate which is the default filter to be selected first.